# 500, Internal Server Error in Retrofit 2

Tags: java, android, server, http-post, retrofit2

I have 500 internal server error, every time when i try to send POST request via Retrofit. When i sending GET request, it sending correctly. I'm sure that with serverside everyting is ok. What's wrong with my code ?

Here is my request method

```
@POST("/listing/createListing")
Call<ResponseBody> pushData(@Body RequestBody image);
```

post implementation modelTask is my model class object and firebaseToken is firebase authentication token. In my model class, I am saving images as a file list.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new 
Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws 
IOException {
            Request newRequest  = chain.request().newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + 
firebaseToken)
                    .build();
            return chain.proceed(newRequest);
        }
    }).build();
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(client)
            .baseUrl("https://something.herokuapp.com")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    ApiEndPoint apiService = retrofit.create(ApiEndPoint.class);


    MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder();
    builder.setType(MultipartBody.FORM);


    builder.addFormDataPart("title", modelTask.getTitle());
    builder.addFormDataPart("description", modelTask.getDescription());
    builder.addFormDataPart("user_name", "Josim Uddin");
    builder.addFormDataPart("user_id", "2133323");
    builder.addFormDataPart("price", "30.0");
    builder.addFormDataPart("category_name", "Cleaning");
    builder.addFormDataPart("category_id", "123");
    builder.addFormDataPart("preferred_date", 
modelTask.getPreferred_date());
    builder.addFormDataPart("preferred_time", 
modelTask.getPreferred_time());
    builder.addFormDataPart("hasPet", modelTask.getHasPet());
    builder.addFormDataPart("budget", 
String.valueOf(modelTask.getBudget()));
    builder.addFormDataPart("address", modelTask.getAddress());
    builder.addFormDataPart("longitude", 
String.valueOf(modelTask.getLongitude()));
    builder.addFormDataPart("latitude", 
String.valueOf(modelTask.getLatitude()));
    builder.addFormDataPart("equipment", modelTask.getEquipment());

    for (int i = 0; i < modelTask.getImages().size(); i++) {
        builder.addFormDataPart("image[]", 
modelTask.getImages().get(i).getName(), 
RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), 
modelTask.getImages().get(i)));
    }


    MultipartBody requestBody = builder.build();
    Call<ResponseBody> call = apiService.pushData(requestBody);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, 
Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse:" + response.code()+", 
"+response.message());

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "post submitted code:" + 
response.code()+"body:"+response.body().string());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to submit post to API:: 
"+t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Postman test is successful.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
@POST("listing/createListing")
Call<ResponseBody> pushData(@Body RequestBody image);
```

Remove "/" from the link and add it to the end of Base Url.